# How to say "the majority of our participants" and follow that with a number and percebtage

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, grammatical-number, numbers, structure

I want to express that the majority of participants and also want to say the number of participants (20) and percentage (50%) were students. I need to use this structure in different contexts. Does the following sentence sound clear and correct?

> The majority of our participants 20 (50%) were students.

Is there a better way to convey the same meaning in a better structure?

Comment: That is standard in scientific papers.

Comment: 50% is half of them, not 'the majority'!

Comment: As @KateBunting says, 50% is *not* "a majority". But assuming that's just a slip of the pen, consider *The majority **(20 participants, being 60%)** were students*. OR ***(60%, being 20 participants)*** - it's all the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sentence looks academic, so I will share my experience of that style.

Most of your sentence works well. The problem is that the number **20** is not correctly attached. It just sits there.

There are two tricks you can apply. The first is to separate the raw number from the percentage. The second is to find the simplest way possible *not* to open the sentence with a number, which by convention would have to be written out. This is not a problem for **20**, which is easily written as *twenty*, but would be horrible for something like 463.

The following fits into a common pattern:

> Of the participants, 20 were students (50%).

Readers can judge for themselves whether this is a **majority** or not.

For the sake of comparison, you may consult this sentence, which I copied from an article on my desktop:

> Of the sample, 875
> identified as male (55.41 %), 652 identified as female (41.29 %), 16
> identified as ‘other’ (mostly irrelevant responses; 1.01 %), and 36
> participants selected ‘prefer not to say’ (2.28 %).

Here is a longer but similar passage from a different article:

> The sample included 180 participants, 62 men and 118 women,
> between 18–33 years of age (M = 19.12, SD = 1.81). Participants
> were volunteers recruited from an online research participation
> system for undergraduate students at Pepperdine University in the
> United States and were compensated with assignment credit in a
> psychology class. The sample consisted mostly of full-time students
> (97.2 %). Of the sample, 53.3 % identified as White, 21.2 % identified
> as Asian, 9.4% identified as Black or African American, 5.4% identified
> as biracial, and less than 1% identified as Native Hawaiian or Pacific
> Islander.

It even integrates the word **mostly** if that still appeals to you.